# How can I get the disassembled bytecode of foo.py?

Tags: python, bytecode

foo.py

```
for i in range(10 ** 8):
    i
```

py_testing.py

```
import foo
import dis
print(dis.dis(foo))
```

When I executed py_testing.py, the output was as follows:

```
None
```

How can I get the disassembled bytecode of `foo.py`?

Comment: A module doesn't have any code to disassemble. Put the code in a function and disassemble that.

Comment: @Barmar But I don't want to use it as I am comparing the speed of execution of the code when put inside the function.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't understand. I can create a .pyc file, but can it give me a disassembled bytecode?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the other question.

Comment: That other question is about decompiling a pyc file, not about disassembly - that's something different.

Comment: From the documentation of `dis.dis()`: **For a module, it disassembles all functions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module objects don't store any record of the bytecode that was executed to initialize the module. Your best bet would be to just open the module's `.py` file and pass the contents to `dis.dis`:

```
with open(foo.__file__) as f:
    dis.dis(f.read())
```

This assumes that the module has a `.py` file.

If importing the module is expensive or has other problematic effects, you can find the module's file with [`importlib.util.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) without importing it:

```
import importlib.util

filepath = importlib.util.find_spec('foo').origin

with open(filepath) as f:
    dis.dis(f.read())
```

Considering the 100-million iteration loop in `foo.py`, I wouldn't want to import that.

Comment: How is ```f.read()``` fine for ```dis``` and a module is not? I mean in both the cases we are passing modules

Comment: No, `f.read()` is a string representing Python source code. It's not a module.